# Loading my .profile into SublimeText2

Tags: shell, environment-variables, sublimetext2

I have a lot of stuff defined in my .profile (paths and such), rvm, virtualenv and other needed bits. I want them to be propagated to all build systems and settings when stuff is run using the ST2 environment (so that stuff runs via a shell subprocess, or at least something is done to load all of this information).

All I see online is that I will need to modify each and every setting per language in ST2 to point to the right executables and paths, which is a chore I don't want to endure. Is there some way to quickly load my shell environment into ST2?

Comment: If you start Sublime from your shell environment it naturally inherits all exported environment variables? Can you be more specific what is wrong with the build system?

Comment: This I've discovered - however I am accustomed to opening my editor from the GUI as well, and then the shell env is not inherited.

Comment: Then make your GUI shortcut icon or whatever execute through your shell. It is not problem per se with Sublime, but configuring whatever operating system you are using.